# Upgrade python script of project to learn scraping

Tags: web-scraping

I found an interesting project to learn scraping here :
https://github.com/0AlphaZero0/Vinted-data/blob/main/README.md

I tried to play the script "collect_data.py" but it gives me the following error :
id_DATA = json.loads(re.findall(id_supported[id_name]["regex"], req)[0])

IndexError: list index out of range

Since the last update of the project was in 2022 maybe the html website changes, could you please give me someadvice to upgrade the script ? i tried with chatgpt but its not working as well.

Thanks

I tried replacing rejex by beautifulsoup but it was not working

Comment: You get IndexError when you try to access something which is not present, so check if the element is present in the list before accessing it.